# How many objects does secant line intersect in a regular grid

Tags: combinatorics

I need general formula for number of intersections of secant with given step and grid of objects. See picture for example. For normalized step=1/2 number of intersections is zero. For step=1/4 number of intersections is 12(tangential contact is not considered an intersection). It depends on parameters a(diameter of object) and d(distrance between objects) and number of objects in a row.

[image: secant intersections with grid of objects]

Comment: It seems that it's a sum of series with signum function. Signum function is kind of bad because basically no way to get exact sum.

Comment: Does it also depend on whether the secant intersects the circles in a column? Also are you assuming the intersecting line is vertical (or horizontal) with respect to the grid of circles? [Finally are you always using circles in the grid?]

Comment: Yes, count number of circles that vertical secant intersects when moving with specified step. For step=1/4 it's 0+6+0+6+0=12. Only vertical secants are needed. It does not matter whether it's circle or square.

Comment: If your normalized step 1/2 is always through the midpoint of the central two columns, it seems each column will be either 0 or 12 since there are six circles in each column. If in your picture you used both vertical lines which are 1/4 unit away from central line at x=1/2, there would be in total 24 here, since another 12 would occur to the right of the vertical midline by symmetry. I think more needs to be specified about what you intend to count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I came to conclusion I will provide answer.

As far as I understand it cannot be expressed in general case in ordinary functions.

Let L be width of grid, n - number of objects in a row, z - number of steps, k - current step. Then

```
L=(n-1)d+a
```

Consider condition when secant intersects column:

```
0<k(n-1)d/z+ka/z-Floor(k(n-1)/z+ka/z/d)d<a (1)
```

Consider function which returns one when secant intersects column:

```
f(k,z)=1, when (1)
f(k,z)=0, otherwise
```

Having such a function we can sum over all steps k to get resulting number of intersections:

```
Sum[f(k,z), {k, 0, z}]
```

I put it into mathematica and got correct answer for case when z=4.

```
ClearAll[f]
f[k_, z_, n_, a_, d_] := 
 1 /; 0 < k*(n - 1)*d/z + k*a/z - Floor[k*(n - 1)/z + k*a/z/d]*d < a
f[k_, z_, n_, a_, d_] := 0

With[{z = 4, n = 6, a = 1, d = 2}, Sum[f[k, z, n, a, d], {k, 0, z}]*n]
12
```

12 is correct answer for this simple case. Mathematica cannot compute general case that depends on n,a,d.